# TS - define Interface which cannot contain both error and payload fields

Tags: typescript, interface

I have a type `Action` which:

1. **MUST** contain a field `type` {`String`}
2. **CAN** contain a field `payload` {`Object<string, any>`}
3. **CAN** contain a field `error` {`Error`}

**constrains**:

- *`IF contains field`* **`payload`** *`THEN it cannot contain field`* **`error`**
- *`IF contains field`* **`error`** *`THEN it cannot contain field`* **`payload`**

---

this is what I did:

```js
interface ActionBase {
  type: string
}

interface ActionError extends ActionBase {
  error: Error
}

interface Action extends ActionBase {
  payload?: Object<string, any>
}
```

External Resource: [`DefinitelyTyped/types/redux-actions/index.d.ts/#L14`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/redux-actions/index.d.ts#L14)

---

Now I am wondering if could exists a way to **define only one interface `Action`** which implements all of this.

**How to achieve what described?**

Note: The question is directly regarding Typescript, but because of the matter, any answer regarding languages which implement interface will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, mostly.

TypeScript lacks [exact types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936), which is what you would want to use to say an object has some properties and no others.

But in this case you have *specific* properties you want to prohibit.  If you specify them as having the `never` type, then it's impossible to put them in (`never` is a special type with no values).  And if you make them optional, then you *can* leave them out.  So an optional property of type `never` is a property that you must leave out.  Here is an example implementation for you:

```
interface ActionBase {
  type: string
}
interface ActionError extends ActionBase {
  error: Error;
  payload?: never;
}
interface ActionPayload extends ActionBase {
  payload: Record<string, any>;
  error?: never;
}
interface ActionNeither extends ActionBase {
  payload?: never;
  error?: never;
}
type Action = ActionError | ActionPayload | ActionNeither;
```

So an `Action` can have an `error` or a `payload` or neither, but not both.  Let's see it working:

```
var a: Action = {
  type: 'thing',
}; // okay, just a type

var a: Action = {
  type: 'thing',
  payload: {'dog': 123}
}; // okay, with payload

var a: Action = {
  type: 'thing',
  error: new Error(),
}; // okay, with error

var a: Action = {
  type: 'thing',
  error: new Error(),
  payload: {'dog': 123}
}; // error! can't do both error and payload
```

That's more or less what you want, I think.  Note these issues:

```
var a: Action = {
  type: 'thing',
  monkey: 12
}; // error, object literal doesn't like extra properties

var a: Action = {
  type: 'thing',
  error: undefined,
  payload: {'dog': 123}
}; // okay, undefined is considered "missing", best we can do with optionals
```

I said you can "mostly" do it only because an optional property can always be set to `undefined`, so nothing prevents a `ActionPayload` from having an *undefined* `error` as opposed to an *absent* `error`.  But that's pretty much the same thing, at least according to TypeScript.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: This is of precious help. I'll wait for somebody else to partecipate to this discussion, but I strongly believe this could be the best way to address it and I'll accept your answer in few days. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not possible. I mean the whole concept of an Interface is to unify common behavior. If you want to distinguish the structure you have to use multiple Interfaces as you did.

Comment: Yes. but, in that case, I have to prevent  `ActionBase` from being implemented. How to do this?